# Explanation of a match between shadows and wet floor at Niagara Falls

Tags: experimental-physics, water, evaporation, shadow

The question is about the cause of a wet-floor phenomenon. My vacation trip started at Niagara Falls (Canadian side, horseshoe fall on the upper left corner). It was around 10-11 AM, not too sunny yet. The sprinkling drops of water left a spur following quite faithfully the shadow of the fence, with an offset:

[image: Wet parts behind the fence]

The floor's wet parts goes deeper toward the street, as can be seen around the first pillar shadow (bottom), than behind the openwork metal fence. People have started creating foot traces, but the phenomenon subsists over the second, third, and perhaps fourth pillar.

What is the cause of this pattern, if not accidental? I thought about two options:

- drops jumping differently around two different obstacles
- protection from evaporation of the floor by the shadow

Comment: Option 2 looks right.  Sun is still rising, so the shadow moves closer to the wall while also moving round.

Comment: While cycling in the woods I've noticed that pot-holes always hide in the shadows. I attribute this to the same phenomenon - it stays wet longer in the shady spots.